# metaclass do not call __prepare__ when use type function

Tags: python, enums

recently I want to convert `Enum` class to django's `ChoicesText` enum class dynamicly use code like below::

```py
class DT(Enum):
  STRING = 'string'
  INT = 'int'

data_type = type('DataType', (django.models.enums.ChoicesText,), {tag:tag.value for tag in DT})
```

it raises `AttributeError`exception:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/enums.py", line 13, in __new__
    for key in classdict._member_names:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_member_names'
```

when debug with a toy script, I found a tricky thing is that, when use `type` as a function to create type, it will not call `__prepare__` like `class` statement. as below:

```py
# metaprepare.py
class Meta1(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcs, name, bases):
        print('call prepare')
        return {}

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, parameters):
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, parameters)




class A(metaclass=Meta1):
    pass


type('C', (A, ), {})
```

execute this script only one `call prepare` print.

```sh
$python metaprepare.py                                                                                                                                                       
$call prepare
```

it is porpose behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is intentional.  When using `type()` to create a new class you are giving it everything it needs:

- the name of the new class
- any classes to inherit from
- the namespace to use as the class body

That last one is important: when using the `class` statement Python will call `__prepare__` to get the namespace to use, but when using `type` you are giving Python the namespace to use -- so it doesn't need to call `__prepare__`.

As far as your original plan, try something like:

```
data_type = django.models.enums.ChoicesText(
        'DataType',
        {tag:tag.value for tag in DT},
        )
```

Comment: thanks, same adjust for answer,  is `TextChoices` not `ChoicesText` :), and use tag will trigger more check in  ``enum``,  instead  use string directlry ```values = [(tag.name, tag.value) for tag in DT]
    DataType = models.enums.TextChoices('DataType', values)```.