# How to decorate an enum in python

Tags: python, enums, python-decorators

I have made a class decorator which allows me to change the `__init__` function of any class, which looks like this:

```
def find_init(cls):
    """ Finds the init function of a class """
    bases = [cls]
    while bases:
        curr_cls = bases.pop(0)
        if '__init__' in curr_cls.__dict__:
            return curr_cls.__dict__['__init__']
        else:
            bases += curr_cls.__bases__

def decorate(cls, create_init):
    d = dict(cls.__dict__)
    d['__init__'] = create_init(find_init(cls))
    return type(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, d)

def decorator(cls):
    def create_init(original):
        def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("You've been decorated")
            original(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return new_init
        
    return decorate(cls, create_init)
```

This works as expected for a regular class, or an inherited class. However, applying the decorator to an Enum causes an error:

```
@decorator
class test(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        print("Hi")
```

Output:

```text
Hi
Hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\Work\Python\FlockingGame\stinkers\flocking py\enumtest.py", line 30, in <module>
    class test(Enum):
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\Work\Python\FlockingGame\stinkers\flocking py\enumtest.py", line 25, in decorator
    return decorate(cls, create_init)
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\Work\Python\FlockingGame\stinkers\flocking py\enumtest.py", line 16, in decorate
    return type(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, d)
  File "D:\Tools\Python\Python_3.10\lib\enum.py", line 198, in __new__
    enum_members = {k: classdict[k] for k in classdict._member_names}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_member_names'
```

And on top of that, the init function for the enum is being called before the decorator is even applied.

How would I go about achieving the desired effect for an Enum?

Comment: Decorators run only after the class is defined, which is after the enum variants have been instantiated. There is no way to achieve what you want with a decorator. (And why would you want to do this anyway? This looks like a strange problem to want to solve. A less academic example would go a long way.)

Comment: More concretely I am using this to add objects to an update queue, such that when an instance is created it gets automatically added to the queue. This could be achieved by manually adding it to the queue in the classes init function, but it is more intuitive to use in decorator form.

Comment: That looks like an even stranger problem to want to solve. Why would you ever want to ‘update’ an enum member? They are supposed to be completely static and immutable.

Comment: Because I am storing additional information in the enum members that I want to update

Comment: By using `type()` you're circumventing a lot of build-up (look for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62128254/14311263)). In particular, you don't use the `__prepare__` of the `EnumMeta` which builds a very specific namespace (with an attribute `_member_names`), that then is used in `__new__`. In combination with the fact that all enum instances are _created during class construction_ (as pointed out by @user3840170), you're into all kinds of trouble. Don't do it, won't work with enums. Your use case seems rather strange?

Comment: The decorator approach will not work well, if at all, with enums.  You can  look at the `__init_subclass__` method, which might help (although it is also called during class creation, before any decorator can run).  Can you give an example of one of your enums, and the data you want to update?  There is probably another approach that will work with enums.